# Executing a callback one time after a function and its super functions have finished execution

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to execute a callback after a function and its super functions have finished execution.

It's important that:

- The callback is executed only once
- The callback is executed synchronously
- The class methods are called in the provided order
- The callback be specified one time, and not passed every time the function is called. The goal here is to provide event-listener style functionality

Given the following example:

```js
class Car {
  constructor(props) {
    this.props = props;
  }

  brake() {
    this.activateBrakes();
  }

  activateBrakes() {
    console.log('1');
  }
}

class Prius extends Car {
  brake() {
    super.brake();

    this.activateRegenerativeBrakingSystem();
  }

  activateRegenerativeBrakingSystem() {
    console.log('2');
  }
}

var onBrake = () => console.log('after');

var car = new Car({onBrake});
car.brake();

var prius = new Prius({onBrake});
prius.brake();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pL4jzcwv/20/

How can I get the console to print:

```
"1"
"after"
"1"
"2"
"after"
```

I'm not calling onBrake because, as far as I can tell, there’s nowhere it can be put, as-is, to make the console log what is described.

Comment: (This is a well-asked question.)

Comment: is this what you want to achieve? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pL4jzcwv/23/)

Comment: @guijob not quite - I don't want to have to pass the callback to the function every time, just on class instantiation. The idea is to be able to register a callback once and then have it be called every time without mentioning it again

Comment: what environment do you run your script in? Node or browser?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this:

1. Make the *implementation* of braking separate from the method `brake`, and have `Car`'s `brake` call the callback.

```
class Car {
  // ...
  brake() {
    this.brakeImplementation(); // <==
    this.props.onBrake();       // <==
  }

  brakeImplementation() {       // <==
    this.activateBrakes();      // <==
  }                             // <==
  // ...
}
```

(And `Prius` overrides `brakeImplementation`, not `brake`.)

Live Example:

```js
class Car {
  constructor(props) {
    this.props = props;
  }

  brake() {
    this.brakeImplementation();
    this.props.onBrake();
  }
  
  brakeImplementation() {
    this.activateBrakes();
  }

  activateBrakes() {
    console.log('1');
  }
}

class Prius extends Car {
  brakeImplementation() {
    super.brakeImplementation();

    this.activateRegenerativeBrakingSystem();
  }

  activateRegenerativeBrakingSystem() {
    console.log('2');
  }
}

var onBrake = () => console.log('after');

var car = new Car({onBrake});
car.brake();

var prius = new Prius({onBrake});
prius.brake();
```

2. Have a method, say `doneBraking`, which accepts a constructor and only calls the callback if the constructor passed in is the constructor of the instance:

```
doneBraking(ctor) {
  if (ctor === this.constructor) {
    this.props.onBrake();
  }
}
```

Then put a call to it at the end of `brake` in every class:

```
class Car {
  // ...
  brake() {
    this.activateBrakes();
    this.doneBraking(Car); // <==
  }
  // ...
}

class Prius extends Car {
  // ...
  brake() {
    super.brake();

    this.activateRegenerativeBrakingSystem();
    this.doneBraking(Prius);                  // <==
  }
  // ...
}
```

A bit ugly, but... :-) Live Example:

```js
class Car {
  constructor(props) {
    this.props = props;
  }

  brake() {
    this.activateBrakes();
    this.doneBraking(Car);
  }

  activateBrakes() {
    console.log('1');
  }
  
  doneBraking(ctor) {
    if (ctor === this.constructor) {
      this.props.onBrake();
    }
  }
}

class Prius extends Car {
  brake() {
    super.brake();

    this.activateRegenerativeBrakingSystem();
    this.doneBraking(Prius);
  }

  activateRegenerativeBrakingSystem() {
    console.log('2');
  }
}

var onBrake = () => console.log('after');

var car = new Car({onBrake});
car.brake();

var prius = new Prius({onBrake});
prius.brake();
```

Comment: First example is cleaner, but seems problematic when Prius gets subclassed potentially. Second example is solid, but like you said a little bit ugly. Both seem like valid solutions. Thoughts on this? https://jsfiddle.net/pL4jzcwv/33/

Comment: The main limitation of it seems to be that the onBrake method can't easily be called with arguments, unless data is passed around via context (this)

Comment: @maxhud: I'm afraid I didn't understand your second comment above. Re the first: The pattern just continues ad infinitum, `PriusSpecial` overrides `brakeImplementation` and calls `super.brakeImplementation` just like `Prius` does.

Comment: Ah yes - first solution looks good. My second comment was about the jsfiddle link in my first comment

Answer (score 0):

May be I misunderstood you but you mentioned event loops and I came with idea to push your callback `onBrake` to event loop as a next **io** task (process.nextTick), then it is possible to implement the idea with `async` functions.

The following example will work only in **node.js**.

```
class Emitter {
  constructor(props) {
    this.events = []
  }
  add(event) {
    if (!this.events.includes(event.name)) {
      this.events.push(event.name)
      process.nextTick(event)
    }
  }
  remove(event) {
    this.events = this.events.filter(name => name !== event.name)
  }
}
class Car {
  constructor(props) {
    this.props = props
    this.event = new Emitter()
  }
  async brake() {
    this.activateBrakes()
    this.onBrake()
  }
  activateBrakes() {
    console.log(1)
  }
  async onBrake () {
    this.event.add(this.props.onBrake)
  }
}

class Prius extends Car {
  async brake() {
    super.brake()
    this.activateRegenerAtiveBrakingSystem()
    this.onBrake()
  }
  activateRegenerAtiveBrakingSystem() {
    console.log(2)
  }
  drive() {
    this.event.add(() => console.log(` drive`))
  }
}

const onBrake = () => console.log(`✋ stop`)

async function main() {
  const car = new Car({onBrake})
  await car.brake()

  const prius = new Prius({onBrake})
  prius.brake()
  prius.drive()
}

main()
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think this would be asynchronous, correct? I need this to be synchronous. Regardless it’s in the browser, unfortunately:)